# SpringBoot CascadeType ALL vs MERGE and detached entities

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Link extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String title;


    @NonNull
    private String url;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "link")
    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    @Transient
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private String userAlias ;

    public String getUserAlias() {

        if(user == null)
            return "";

        return user.getAlias();


    }

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Long getUser() {
        if(user == null)
            return -1L;

        return user.getId();
    }

    public void addComment(Comment c) {
        comments.add(c);
        c.setLink(this);

    }




}

@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Comment extends Auditable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Link link;

    public Long getLink() {
        return link.getId();
    }


}
```

If I create a comment and a link, associate the link to the comment and then save that works.

Eg:

```
Link link = new Link("Getting started", "url");
Comment c = new Comment("Hello!");
link.addComment(c);
linkRepository.save(link);
```

However, if I save the comment first:

```
Link link = new Link("Getting started", "url");
Comment c = new Comment("Hello!");
commentRepository.save(c);
link.addComment(c);
linkRepository.save(link);
```

I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on uk.me.dariosdesk.dariodemo.domain.Comment.link references an unknown entity: uk.me.dariosdesk.dariodemo.domain.Link
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1815) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1759) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1646) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:287) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:903) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:934) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.0.Final.jar:5.4.0.Final]
```

Changing the cascade type from ALL to MERGE seems to fix the problem and accept both implementations. (Ie: Adding a pre-existing comment or creating both and then saving via the link)

1) Why is this?
2) Is there anything I should be aware of in using MERGE rather than ALL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repository save method checks if entity exist. For new entity persist is called, for persisted entity merge is called.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

In 2nd use-case Link is new entity, therefore persist() is called. With CascadeType.ALL persist() is cascaded to Comment entity. Comment is already persisted and needs to be merged, persist() fails.

If you use CascadeType.MERGE persist() is not cascaded down to Comment. It does not fail.